# What make upcasting and downcasting illegal

Tags: c++, downcast

During lecture some student said this upcasting and downcasting lacks logic and is illegal. Some how the teacher got confused and agreed and said he will review and do the lecture again but i dont know what is wrong with this code and is there a scenario where this would be illegal.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base {
public:
        int a,b;
        base(){
        a=0;
        b=1;}
};
class derived : public base {
public:
    int c,d;
    derived(){
    c=2;
    d=3;
    }
};
int main(){
    derived der;
    base baseob;
    derived *derptr=new derived;
    derptr=(derived*)&baseob;
    base *baseptr=new base;
    baseptr=&der;
}
```

Edited:
Scratch the above code it was something i was working on but like it was pointed out the memory leak was occurring(stupid of me not to see that) here is the new code now i only want to know is it legal or not? (dynamic cast was to be taught after this so no examples of dynamic cast please)

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
class Employee 
{ 
public: 
Employee(string fName, string lName, double sal) 
{ 
FirstName = fName; 
LastName = lName; 
salary = sal; 
} 
string FirstName; 
string LastName; 
double salary; 
void show() 
{ 
cout << "First Name: " << FirstName << " Last Name: " << LastName << " Salary: " << salary<< endl; 
} 
void addBonus(double bonus) 
{ 


salary += bonus; 
} 
}; 
class Manager :public Employee 
{ 
public: 
Manager(string fName, string lName, double sal, double comm) :Employee(fName, lName, sal) 
{ 
Commision = comm; 
} 
double Commision; 
double getComm() 
{ 
return Commision; 
} 
};
```

For downcasting

```
    int main() { Employee e1("Ali", "Khan", 5000); //object of base class 
    //try to cast an employee to 
    Manager Manager* m3 = (Manager*)(&e1); //explicit downcasting 
    cout << m3->getComm() << endl; return 0; }
```

For upcasting

```
int main() 
    { 
    Employee* emp; //pointer to base class object 
    Manager m1("Ali", "Khan", 5000, 0.2); //object of derived class 
    emp = &m1; //implicit upcasting 
    emp->show(); //okay because show() is a base class function 
    return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: there is leak of memory because you get memory by calling `new` but you don't call `delete` for free pointer. Besides, your pointer is missing after you set it to local object: `derptr=(derived*)&baseob;` and `baseptr=&der;`. It is extremely wrong! Upcasting and Downcasting no matter here. You should read about `new` and `delete` and `pointers` in C++

Comment: There is only one cast, the downcast `(derived*)&baseob`, and it's illegal as `baseob` is not a `derived`. `baseptr=&der` is valid, but is not a cast.

Comment: @molbdnilo, it's not a "cast" as defined by C++ but it's an implicit upcast, which is commonly used terminology even if it isn't a formal C++ term.

Comment: @Saad please do use a favor and make your code example readable by formatting it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of leaking memory, this is not the recommend way of casting. The provided example uses C-style casts, though they work, then can easily lead to undefined behaviour (if types hierarchy mismatches).

Upcasting via `baseptr=&der;` is fine, although a more common call would be to simply:

```
base* baseptr = new derived();
```

This will always work if the created object is of a derived class.

Downcasting should be performed via a `dynamic_cast`, e.g.:

```
base* baseptr = new base();
derived* derptr = dynamic_cast<derived>(baseptr); // will fail, derptr == nullptr
```

If a pointer cannot be cast into a derived (really  - extended in regards to base) class, `dynamic_cast` will return a nullptr. You should check for that. In the example above, the casting will fail and `derptr == nullptr` resolves to `true`.

Comment: The problem with dynamic_cast is, that the base class need to have at least one virtual function, which is not the case for the OPs example.

Comment: And RTTI must be activated. See your compiler documentation to learn how to.

Answer (score 2):

If you downcast, you have to be sure that the runtime type of the object being casted is really of the target type. When you cast the pointer to `baseob` to a pointer to `derived`, you played foul with the type system, because now you have a pointer to `derived` that does not point to `derived`.